# Sql table adding constraint to check for number limit

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl, check-constraint

I am creating a table in oracle DB and trying to add constraint so that the numbers allowed in the column are 1,2,3.

```
CREATE TABLE "TABLE_EXAMPLE"
(
.
.
"PROTOCOL" NUMBER (1,2,3),

....)

CONSTRAINT "CH1"
        CHECK ("PROTOCOL" BETWEEN 1 AND 3),
```

Am I doing right or any better way?

Comment: There is no `number(1,2,3)`  datatype in Oracle.

Comment: ButI have seen NUMBER (0,1) data type

Comment: `NUMBER(0,1)` isn't an enumeration. It's the number of digits, and the precision.

Comment: @Plouf! `number(0, 1)` is simply wrong declaration, because numeric precision cannot be zero.

Comment: +1 for adding constraints, it's very good database style!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE_EXAMPLE 
(
 ...
  PROTOCOL NUMBER(1) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT CH1 CHECK (PROTOCOL IN (1,2,3))
 ...
);
```

`BETWEEN 1 AND 3` includes 1.5, 1.6, etc.

And I'd recommend not to use quotes `"` unless you have special characters in table or column names...

Comment: whats the difference between NUMBER(1)  and NUMBER(0,1) ?

Comment: The data type `NUMBER` takes two parameters `NUMBER(p,s)`. The first one, `p`, is the precision, the second one, `s` is the scale. There are some examples in the documentation  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements001.htm#sthref117

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to check in the table level Check Constraint is the best way. because if you are inserting larger value then the check constraint ll throw the error.